# Object not recognized in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code in one of my controllers to get access to eventful.

```
eventful = Eventful::API.new('my_key_here')
```

However, I get the following error when I refresh my page

```
uninitialized constant LocationsController::Eventful
```

I installed the gem version 2.2.1 as directed through http://api.eventful.com/libs and my     gemfile contains the line

```
gem 'eventfulapi', '2.2.1'
```

I am trying to recreate the example here: http://api.eventful.com/libs/ruby/doc/index.html
I can get it to work in a separate ruby script (e.x. running 'ruby a.rb' through command line) which leads me to thinking it's totally possible. I just can't get it to work in a controller to feed my application.

Comment: i also ran bundle install and restarted the rails server before reloading my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `require 'eventful/api'` at the top of the controller code.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! I thought about that solution but adding "require <anything>" to the top of controller code seems not best practice. Why is having the Gem in the Gemfile not enough?

Comment: Assuming you're using Rails 3+, I'm guessing it's because the gem's main file is different than the actual gem name, try putting this in your Gemfile: `gem "eventfulapi", "2.2.1", :require => "eventful/api"`.  Take a look [here](http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html) for more information.